dracut-install: Failed to find module 'hid-polostar'
I need to resolve a kernel panic on Fedora 41, but when I boot into the live version and mount my partitions, after reinstalling kernel 6.11.4, it won't let me run dracut. It tells me that I am missing modules, specifically hid-polostar. I don't know what to do at this point; I have already tried everything.
I tried running this command: sudo dracut --force and it gave me this error when trying to generate the kernel image:
dracut-install: Failed to find module 'hid-polostar'
The only way it worked was by running sudo mount --bind /lib /mnt/lib, and from there, it allowed me to create the dracut. However, when I rebooted the computer, Fedora 41 kept loading without finishing.

i will quote the bugzilla (link) after getting the same error:

Dracut failure is a consequence, not the culprit. There is something
qrong with your 3rd party kernel module.

unistallation instructions are here:
https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/tree/master
make dkms_uninstall

or
make uninstall

depending on whether it was a dkms or manual install.
